# Fast enumeration of all perfect matchings in complete graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, permutation

I have a code that generates the list with all possible Perfect Matchings (PM) of a fully connected graph. Each edge of the graph is mono or bi-colored with up to `cmax` different colors. Each edge is labeled as `w[c1, c2, a, b]`, where `c1` and `c2` are the colors of vertex `a` and vertex `b` respectively, with `c1,c2 = 0,...,cmax`.
More than one PM will generate the same coloring. For example, take a graph with 4 vertices `a,b,c,d`: the PM `w[0, 1, a, b]*w[0, 0, c, d]` and the PM `w[0, 0, a, c]*w[1, 0, b, d]` have the same coloring ( `[0, 1, 0, 0]` color in vertices `(a, b, c, d)` respectively). I also want to group together all PM that generate the same colorings.

As the number of graph vertices and/or colors increases, the PM generation slows down pretty quickly. I wonder if there's a way to speed things up. My strategy is the following:

1. Generate all (unweighted) PM
2. Generate a list with all color combinations
3. Assign all possible weight combinations to these PM
4. Save the different colorings

This is my code. It takes 2 seconds for cmax = 3 and n=6 but 39 seconds for cmax = 3 and n = 8.

```
cmax = 3; (* number of colors *)
pathmax = 8; (* number of vertices *)

(* Generate all PM *)
set = ToExpression[FromLetterNumber[Range[pathmax]]];
PMpaths = Union[Sort /@ (Sort /@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[set, {pathmax}])]; 
Print["Number of PM: ", Length[PMpaths]];
cols = Tuples[Range[cmax] - 1, pathmax/2];

(* Generate all weighted PM *)
AllColoredPMs = ConstantArray[0, Length[cols]^2*Length[PMpaths]];
VertexColorings = ConstantArray[0, Length[cols]^2*Length[PMpaths]];
ccPMidx = 1;
ccPMidx2 = 1;
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[PMpaths], ii++,
  For[jj = 1, jj <= Length[cols], jj++,
    For[jj2 = 1, jj2 <= Length[cols], jj2++,
      PMtmp = 1;
      For[kk = 1, kk <= pathmax/2, kk++,
       wtmp = w[cols[[jj, kk]], cols[[jj2, kk]], PMpaths[[ii, kk, 1]], PMpaths[[ii, kk, 2]]];
       PMtmp = PMtmp*wtmp (* construct the PM adding weight by weight *)
       ];
      AllColoredPMs[[ccPMidx++]] = PMtmp;
      (* identify the colors of each PM and save it*)
      CurrVC = PMtmp /. {w[cc1_, cc2_, a_, b_] -> a[cc1]*b[cc2]} /. {Times -> List} /. {x_[c_] -> c};
      VertexColorings[[ccPMidx2++]] = CurrVC;
      ];
    ];
  ];
(* Unique colored *)
UniqueVertexColorings = DeleteDuplicates[VertexColorings];

AllWeights = DeleteDuplicates[Cases[AllColoredPMs, _w, {1, Infinity}]];
Print["Number of PM with all color combinations: ", Length[AllColoredPMs]];
Print["Number of different PM: ", Length[UniqueVertexColorings]];
Print["Total number of weights: ", Length[AllWeights]];
```

Comment: I feel like you could maybe do something clever and/or tricky with `Outer` or `Inner` applied at certain levels and using `w` as a combining head, instead of all those `For` loops, which seem to be slowing things down a great deal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the case `pathmax=6`, I try to use the form `{a,b,c,d,e,f}` instead of `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` for the perfect matchings `PMpaths`. Then I create all possiable color numbers stored in `cols`, and map each entry in cols to `PMpaths` (rearrange the the values in `cols` with the position described by `PMpaths`, see [the link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246602/55474)). Therefore, I can obtain the color assignment for vertices `VertexColorings`.

Instead of using `w[0, 1, a, b]*w[0, 0, c, d]*w[0, 0, e, f]` as weighted perfect matchings, I use the form `{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d, e, f}` for `AllColoredPMs`; then I decompose the AllColoredPMs into the used perfect matchings. For example `{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d, e, f}` is decomposed into the form `{{0, 1, a, b}, {0, 0, c, d}, {0, 0, e, f}}`.

Please see the following code:

```
cmax = 3; 
pathmax = 6; 
set = FromLetterNumber[Range[pathmax]];
PMpaths = Union[Sort /@ (Sort /@ Partition[#, 2] & /@ Permutations[set, {pathmax}])];
PMpaths = Flatten[Map[Flatten, {PMpaths}, {-3}], 1];
Print["Number of PM: ", Length[PMpaths]];

cols = Tuples[Range[cmax]-1, {pathmax}];
VertexColorings = cols[[All, Ordering@#]] & /@ PMpaths;
UniqueVertexColorings = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[VertexColorings, 1]];
AllColoredPMs = Array[Join[cols[[#2]], PMpaths[[#]]] &, Length /@ {PMpaths, cols}];

AllWeightsTmp = Flatten[AllColoredPMs, 1];
AllWeights = Map[Flatten[TakeDrop[#, Length[#]/2] &@Partition[#, 2], {{2}, {1, 3}}]&, AllWeightsTmp];
AllWeights = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[AllWeights, 1]];

Print["Number of PM with all color combinations: ", Length[Flatten[AllColoredPMs, 1]]];
Print["Number of different PM: ", Length[UniqueVertexColorings]];
Print["Total number of weights: ", Length[AllWeights]];
```

For testing time-consuming in the computer:

> `pathmax=6`, your code: **1.1797901sec**, the new code: **0.3312204sec**
> `pathmax=8`, your code: **91.0197936sec**, the new code: **19.4640014sec**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect solution!