# Permuting elements in a nested list according to another nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have two lists (`value` and `label`). With the function `Permute`, I can permute the positions of the elements of `value` according to the permutation `label`.

Namely, the letters `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"` correspond to position numbers `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` , and I want to arrange the number of `value` in the position described by `label`.

> As a simple example:
>
> ```
> value= {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}; 
> label = {"a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}; 
> Permute[value, LetterNumber[label]]
> ```
>
> give the result:`{0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0}`

When the two listed are both nested lists, I wonder whether one can directly use `Permute` as following:

```
value= {{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1}};
label = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e", "c", "f"}, {"a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}};

ii=2;
Permute[value, LetterNumber[label[[ii]]]]
```

**It gives some errors and doesn't work.** However, when I make `ii=1`, there is no error. It seems one cannot use `Permute` directly in nested lists.

One way is to use for-loop. However the calaulation will slow down when the two lists get larger and larger.

```
AllVC= {};
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[label], ii++,  
   For[jj = 1, jj <= Length[value], jj++,  
       CurrVC = Permute[value[[jj]], LetterNumber[label[[ii]]]];
       AppendTo[AllVC, CurrVC];
     ];
  ];
```

Is it possiable to use `Permute` for nested lists without using loops? Is there any simple and quike way to do the above task when lists get large? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `Map[Permute[#, LetterNumber[label[[ii]]]] &]@value`

Comment: thank you!@kglr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** `Table`

```
Table[Permute[i, j], {j, LetterNumber@label}, {i, value}]
```

[image]

**2.** `Outer`

```
Outer[Permute[#2, #] &, LetterNumber[label], value, 1]
```

[image]

**3.** `Array`

```
Array[Permute[value[[#2]], LetterNumber@label[[#]]] &, Length /@ {label, value}]
```

[image]

**4.** `Part` + `Map`:

```
value[[All, LetterNumber @ #]] & /@ label
```

[image: {{{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1}}}]

**5.** You can also use `Ordering` instead of `LetterNumber`:

```
value[[All, Ordering @ #]] & /@ label
```

[image]

Comment: wow, amazing! thank you so much!

Comment: I have another question in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246638/55474), could you help to have a look? @kglr

Answer (score 2):

In your example the lengths of "value" and "label" are different. I added to "label":

```
value = {{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
    0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1}};
label = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "d", "e", "c", 
    "f"}, {"a", "b", "d", "f", "c", "e"}, {"a", "b", "d", "f", "c", 
    "e"}};
MapThread[Permute, {value, LetterNumber /@ label}]

(* {{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1,
   2, 1, 0}} *)
```

Comment: ha, I somehow don't want the lists have the same length. But also good way to extend to same length. Thank you!