# Definition of multiple variables from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions, variable

I have a list of the form

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d, e, f}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, a, c, b, d, f, e}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, b, f, c, a, d, e}, ... }
```

and I would like to translate it into variables of the form `w[c1, c2, x, y]` following these rules:

- the values `c1` and `c2` are taken from the numeric values of each sublist in order
- the values of `x` and `y` are taken from the string values of each sublist in order but each pair is reordered in alphanumeric order.

Following my example, I expect something of the form:

```
{w[0, 0, a, b] w[0, 0, c, d] w[0, 0, e, f], w[0, 0, a, c] w[0, 0, b, d] w[0, 1, e, f], w[2, 2, b, f] w[2, 2, a, c] w[1, 2, d, e], ...}
```

(notice the terms `w[2, 2, c, a]` must be `w[2, 2, a, c]` and similarly with `w[0, 1, e, f]`)

I can use a replace function of the form `/. {c1_,c2_,c3_,c4_, ..., a1_,a2_,a3_,a4,...} -> w[c1,c2,a1,a2] ...`  but it does not seem a very optimal solution. Besides, I will need to generalize it in case I change the number of elements in my initial list.

This question is a follow-up to a previous question: [Fast enumeration of all perfect matchings in complete graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246567/fast-enumeration-of-all-perfect-matchings-in-complete-graph), where the solution was Ok for that purpose, but now I need to recover the variables in this particular form.

Comment: Are the products between the different `w[]` meant to be products? Or is it a typo for missing comas?

Comment: They have to be products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[w, reShape]

SetAttributes[w, Orderless]

reShape = w @@@ Join[##, 2] & @@ ArrayReshape[#, {2, 3, 2}] &;
```

***Example:***

```
lst = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a, b, c, d, e, f}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, a, c, 
    b, d, f, e}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, b, f, c, a, d, e}};

Map[reShape] @ lst
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly!